# How to take value from dynamically created text boxes to excel sheet in VB.net this is the code I am using

Tags: vb.net

This is the Code I am using to create textboxes dynamically and I want to get values from them into the excel sheet

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form4
    Public Property workbook As Object
    Dim x As Single
    Public Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i As Single
        For i = 1 To 100
            Dim textbox(i) As TextBox
        Next
        x = InputBox("Enter No of factors")
        For i = 1 To x
            Dim Combobox1 As New ComboBox
            Combobox1.Name = "Textbox" & i
            Combobox1.Size = New Size(150, 20)
            Combobox1.Location = New Point(10, i * 25)
            Me.Controls.Add(Combobox1)
            Combobox1.Items.Add("Length")
            Combobox1.Items.Add("Breadth")
            Combobox1.Items.Add("Height")
            Combobox1.Items.Add("Other")
        Next

        For i = 1 To x
            Dim textbox As New TextBox
            textbox.Name = "Textbox" & i
            textbox.Size = New Size(150, 20)
            textbox.Location = New Point(250, i * 25)
            Me.Controls.Add(textbox)

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim worksheet As excel.Worksheet
        Dim workbook As excel.Workbook
        Dim app As New excel.Application
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\3.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 1 To x
            workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(2, 1).value = textbox(i).Text

        Next
        Me.Close()
        workbook.Save()
        app.Quit()

    End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `For Each` to find all `TextBox` created in our form and then you can manipulate your `TextBox` as you want :

```
 For Each ctl1 In ctl.Controls
         If TypeOf ctl1 Is TextBox Then
             workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, 1).value = ctl1.Text
          End If 
 Next
```

Comment: How to make it work in case of copying values from multiple textboxes into different cells?